# Charge distribution on a discharged conductor

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, conductors, equilibrium

**Question**

I am trying to prove that given a conductor with **zero net charge** on it then the charges necessarily distributes on its surface so that **the density is zero at every point**.

We can assume the definition of conductor so that *an electron moves freely inside of it (i.e. it does not need to develop work in the process)* and we can also assume **stationary conditions** and all the immediate consequences (e.g.: zero field inside the conductor, equipotential surface, Coulumb's Theorem, ...). Moreover we can also assume that, given the potential on the surface, there exists a unique distribution which satisfies this condition (i.e. we are assuming that the solution of Laplace's Equation with a Boundary Condition exists and is unique for a conductor), notice however that my problem is that the charge is given, not the potential.

**Motivation**

The reason behind my request is that it could allow me to conclude that the charge on a conductor determines its potential (otherwise the same charge would give different potentials and using the principle of superposition I can reach a contradiction by using the above statement).

---

Any comment or answer is welcome and let me know if I can explain myself any clearer!

Answer (score 0):

The assumption of zero net charge is not necessary. Also for a conductor with finite conductivity, this is valid only after relaxation, ie the stationary state.

This can be seen using the local Ohm’s law:
$$
E=\sigma j
$$
with $\rho$ the resistivity, $E$ electric field and $j$ current density. Injecting it into the continuity equation:
$$
\partial_t\rho+\nabla\cdot j=0 
$$
with $\rho$ charge density and using Gauss’ law:
$$
\nabla \cdot E=\frac{\rho}{\epsilon_0}
$$
you get:
$$
\partial_t\rho+\frac{\sigma}{\epsilon_0}\rho=0
$$
Thus, assuming $\sigma$ is independent of $\rho$ (which is not the case in general), you get an exponential relaxation to:
$$
\rho=0
$$
as you wanted.

In fact, you can view this as the continuous analogue of an RC circuit. More precisely, you can model a real conductor by a discrete mesh of leaky capacitors. As the mesh gets finer, you’ll retrieve the continuum limit.

Hope this helps.